# How could I add the parent group as the right most column?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have this report layout:

```
detail 1 | detail 2 | parent group 1

detail 3 | detail 4 |
```

I cannot make the parent `group 1` display as the `right most` column it will always display as `leftmost` column.

Seems like a reasonable scenario but not possible.
Is it true?

Looks like I usually ask too difficult / impossible questions as I do not get solutions (Stacia ignoring me LOL)
However this is the scenario I need for a report

Comment: Have you found any solution to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there's a Table property called **LayoutDirection** that will put the Parent Group as the right hand column when you change the LTR (Left to Right) with RTL.
[image]

Comment: Thanks unfortunately that will also move my details to the leftmost which creates even bigger issues

Comment: I have 2 groups; the outmost group I need to have it display as the rightmost column; the second parent group I do not need to display however within that group I need to move the rows from detail section that appears once per group; in the detail group I may have one or two columns (3 reports that are similar)

Comment: Like in your image how can you move Physisican parent group to the left most column; in my case I will have at the Physisican parent group more than one column

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. You can make your other group column hidden and display the details. Maybe you can edit your original post and add a pic of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is a sub-tablix (tablix inside tablix or more specific to this case a tablix inside a group of merged cells).

1. So you configure as normal detail 1 to detail n, parent group 1 if you have already started, namely to get the headings and detail expressions however later you have to separate but will explain shortly - not overly tedious.
2. Duplicate as in copy and paste your original tablix but remove the parent column at the end - this is your sub (child)-tablix.
3. Pays also at this point to delete the header row of the child-matrix since the parent has the headers.
4. Then in the original Parent tablix configure the (Details) group to group by "parent group 1"
5. Select all the detail cells (just the detail cells only i.e. not headers or entire column) and merge into one cell.
6. Providing you have not touched any cell widths the child-matrix should be the same width and height and columns are aligned with your single merged cell plus headers of the parent. Drag and drop (or cut and paste) and place the sub-matrix into the single merge cell.

The same concept works also if say you want parent columns to be left and right as it really does not matter where the position of Details 1 to Details N are.